# Unable to include macro file in FTL

Tags: moqui

I am trying to include a macro file in the FTL.

As per my understanding with the framework, if we include the macro file using  tag in the xml and render a FTL in this xml, the defined macros should be automatically available in Freemarker template. But this is not working for me.

Also, I have tried to include the macro file in FTL itself using `<#import>` and `<#include>` tag, by providing absolute and relative path both. Either way is not working.

Please suggest what should be the best possible way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code which you've tried and is not working?

Comment: Also instead of "not working" you could tell what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a macro in the FTL file just import the macro file in the destination FTL file and render the destination FTL file in the screen. Here is a simple example

Create a macro FTL file in the `webroot/screen/includes/MacroExample.ftl`

```
<#macro macroExample>
   This is a macro example
</#macro>
```

Import the file in the `Header.html.ftl`

```
 <#import "MacroExample.ftl" as m> <#-- If the macro file in different directory you can use the relative path -->
 <@m.macroExample/>
```

This `Header.html.ftl` is rendered in the `webroot.xml` file by the following code

```
<render-mode>
     <text type="html" location="component://webroot/screen/includes/Header.html.ftl"/>
</render-mode>
```

Now the `macroExample` will be visible in the Header. This is a normal example. You can follow this step to work your.